# Python: Dinamically adding properties to a class

Tags: python, class, dynamic, properties, attributes

I want to dinamically modify a class by adding a property and a class attribute.
It trully has to be dinamically because I'm building a symbolic execution engine so 
the classes are user-defined and I can't modify the code.

For example, suppose that the user-defined class is the next:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

What I exactly want to achive is this, but dinamically:

```
class X:

    _engine = None

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._engine.my_get_method(self, "data")

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        return self._engine.my_set_method(self, "data", value)
```

So I hook every get or set to the data attribute.

In the engine I have something like this, but I can't find a way to
set the property:

```
class Engine:

    def my_get_method(self, attr_name):
        ...

    def my_set_method(self, attr_name, value):
        ...

    def modify_dinamically(self, the_class):
        for attr_name in class_attr_names:
            setattr(the_class, "_engine", self)
            setattr(the_class, attr_name, property(...)) # set the property in some way
```

Things to consider: When I call the engine set and get, I have to pass the instance and the attribute name as parameters.

Is there a way to do this?